# Rails devise reset password not working 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise in a rails 3 application. I have devise fully working however the 'forgot password' function has decided to stop working. When I enter an email address and click the 'send me reset instructions' button I am redirected to the login page which displays a flash notice saying please login first. I have also found out that 'send me reset instructions' is trying to access http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/password. I previously had this working and now its decided to stop working. I do not think it has anything to do with any form of authorization like ACL9. Has anyone experienced the same similar problem. Are there any possible solutions to fixing this.

**Devise/Password_controller.rb**

```
class Devise::PasswordsController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication
  include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers

  access_control do
      allow all
  end

  # GET /resource/password/new
  def new
    build_resource({})
    render_with_scope :new
  end

  # POST /resource/password
   def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(params[resource_name])

    if successful_and_sane?(resource)
      set_flash_message(:notice, :send_instructions) if is_navigational_format?
      respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new }
    end

  rescue => e;
    puts e.backtrace;
    raise e;
  end

  # GET /resource/password/edit?reset_password_token=abcdef
  def edit
    self.resource = resource_class.new
    resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
    render_with_scope :edit
  end

  # PUT /resource/password
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(params[resource_name])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
      set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :edit }
    end
  end

  protected

    # The path used after sending reset password instructions
    def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
      new_session_path(resource_name)
    end

end
```

> 

```
  ProjectRails::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  #SMTP

  #SMTP

      config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "0.0.0.0:3000" }
      config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
      config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "smtp.example.example.ltd.uk",
                                             :user_name => "example.service@example.co.uk",
                                             :password => "1Plonker",
                                             :authentication => "login" }

  end


       config/intializers/devise 

          config.mailer_sender = "Project@example.co.uk"
```

Comment: paste you passwords_controller code

Comment: You have `devise :recoverable` in your model, yes?

Comment: have you tried removing the `access controll do ` portoin? if yes then paste your application_controller as well

Comment: Removing the access control from where? Here is my pastie for my application_controller

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/dipskswt2hdauskwrjlcg

Comment: i think you need to remove this line `rescue_from 'Acl9::AccessDenied', :with => :access_denied` from application controller. then try again. Hopefully this will  fix the issue

Comment: If I get rid of that line surely it will mess up the rest of the authorization throughout my application..Further to this I just tried removing the line and it does the same

Comment: may b the errors are on console... ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3993/discussion-between-user532339-and-sannankhalid)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run rake routes to check that it is routing to the correct location. Also check your view/password/new.html.erb and check that the URL is routing to your login path instead of :url => password_path(resource_name) as this is a common problem. This should solve your problem. Also change your

```
:location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
```

to

```
:location => (whatever the login path is)
```

:-)

Answer (score 1):

You're running this is a development environment, right?
Have you checked the following is correct:

```
# config/environments/development.rb

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mydomain.com' }

# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.mailer_sender = "youremail@domain.com"
```

Comment: And yes I am running this in development and I have what you have suggested

Comment: You should add `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` to your development.rb file.

Comment: I've have this included see my updated post that contains the full development.rb